# Error when calling destructor

Tags: c++

Hi I was learning operator overloading.. i noticed the program crashes when calling the destructor.. any help is appreciated.
Thanks

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Overload
{
private:
    int a, *b;
public:
    Overload():a(0) {cout << "default\n"; };
    Overload(int x);
    Overload operator+(Overload & rhs);
    int geta();
    int* getb();
    void setb();
    void PrintVals(const Overload & val);
    ~Overload();
};


Overload::Overload( int x)
{
    cout << "Parameterized constructor\n";
    a = x;
    b = new int[a];
}


int Overload::geta()
{
    return a;
}


int* Overload::getb()
{
    return b;
}

void Overload::setb()
{
    int val;
    cout << "setting b values\n";
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= a; i++)
    {
        cin >> val;

        b[i] = val;
    }
}



Overload Overload::operator+(Overload & rhs)
{
    Overload temp;
    temp.a  = this->a + rhs.a;
    temp.b = new int[temp.a];
    *temp.b =  *(this->b) + *(rhs.b);

    cout << "inside overload + vale of LHS:" << *(this->b) << endl;
    cout << "inside overload + vale of RHS:" << *(rhs.b) << endl;
    cout << "inside overload + vale of temp:" << *temp.b << endl;
    cout << "Address of b(temp):" << temp.b << endl;


    temp.b++;
    this->b++;
    rhs.b++;

    *temp.b =  *(this->b) + *(rhs.b);

    cout << "inside overload + vale of LHS:" << *(this->b) << endl;
    cout << "inside overload + vale of RHS:" << *(rhs.b) << endl;
    cout << "inside overload + vale of temp:" << *temp.b << endl;

    cout << "Address of b(temp):" << temp.b << endl;



    return temp;
}


 Overload::~Overload()
 {
 cout << "Destructor \n";
 cout << "Address deallocated b:" << b;
 delete [] b;
 }



void Overload::PrintVals(const Overload & val)
{
    int val1, *val2;

    val1 = this->a;
    val2 = this->b;

    cout << "Printing values: a: " << val1 << " b:" << *val2;
}


int main()
{
    Overload X(1),Y(1),Z;
    int val1, *val, val2, val3;
    //Z = X + Y;

    val1 = Y.geta();
    val2 = X.geta();

    Y.setb();


    val = Y.getb();
    printf("val of y  b: %d\n",*val);
    printf("val of x  a: %d\n",val1);

    X.setb();

    val = X.getb();
    printf("val of x b: %d\n",*val);
    printf("val of x a: %d\n",val2);


    Z = X + Y;

    val  = Z.getb();
    val3 = Z.geta();
    val--;

    for( int i = 0; i < val3; i++)
    {
        printf("address of (b) Z: %p \n",val);
        printf("val of z b: %d\n",*val);
        printf("val of z a: %d\n",val3);
        val++;

    }

}
```

OUTPUT:...
Destructor 
Part1(4815,0x7fff73def300) malloc: *** error for object 0x100200004: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Address deallocated b:0x100200004(lldb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) and [assignment operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)) also.

Answer (score 3):

The default constructor leaves `b` uninitialised. In other words, your code doesn't construct the object in a valid state. `b` may be anything when the destructor calls `delete[] b` this causes an error -- what else did you expect?

A related problem is that the default constructed copy constructor and copy assignment operator will simply copy `b`. Thus if the object copied from is destroyed, the object copied to is left with a dangling pointer, which on its destruction will cause an error.

The main lesson is: **don't use raw pointers** if you're not knowing what you're doing (and you don't). Rather use `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` or other methods provided by the standard that will take care of such things for you.

Answer (score 3):

There are TWO nasty errors that cause your error:

**1.Buffer overflow:**

The first fatal error is a buffer overflow in `setb()` : `b` points to an array of `a` elements, so you cannot set b[a] without risking to corrupt memory:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)  // strictly < a, not <=a !!
```

**2.Default copy of raw pointers:**

The second fatal error is in the implementation of `operator+ ()`.  The problem is that a copy of `temp` gets returned (copy construction of an anonymous temporary object in the calling expression) and is then assigned to Z (assignment operator) :

```
Overload temp;  // you create a logcal temporary object
...
temp.b = new int[temp.a];  // you allocate the array
...
return b;   // you return a COPY of the temp object 
}           // here the local temp object gets destroyed
```

But as you didn't define neither the copy constructor, nor the assignement operator, the default ones are used.  These make a memberwise copy of your object, i.e. pointers are just copied as they are.  The result is that `Z.b` will contain a copy of the pointer `temp.b`, but `temp.b` was already deleted at end of operator+() ! Thus Z will refer to a dangling pointer, causing lot of harm, especially when leaving main() the destructor of Z will try dto delete it a second time !

Create a copy constructor and an assignment operator, that correctly allocates a new `b` pointer. This will solve the second problem.

And please, don't increment the pointers of your operands as you do `(this->b++`): it changes the b poitner for good, and delete would not recognize it when the operand goes out of scope.

*By the way, even if its not the direct cause of the problem here, you initalize the `temp` size `a` by adding the sizes of the two operand, but you allocate `b` only for the size of the first operand.*

**3. Other remarks:**

Your default constructor doesn't initialize `b` to `nullptr` explicitely.  It would be a safe practice to do so, but this is not the direct cause of the problem you have here.

In operator+() it would be a good practice to initialize the temp without accessing to its internals:  `Overload temp (a);` will be more maintenable and less error prone.

I don't know if it's your intent, but only the first value of the array pointed by b gets added: `*temp.b =  *(this->b) + *(rhs.b);`  As in `main()` you use at maximum a size of 1, it's not a problem here.  But for the future, better use a loop to copy all elements.

A last remark:  have you ever thought that users of your class could do weird things, such as:  `Overload E, G(0), H(1);  E = H+G;` wouldn't your operator+ then try to access a null pointer ?